# How to get a collection from controller to view via jquery ajax call in done() -mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having two dropdownbox, on selection change of one I want to fill the suitable data to the second one asynchronously. For this I am using Jquery ajax, which passes data to action method. But here the problem I don't know how to pass the collection from that action method back to the view in done()/success() of ajax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial from Rick Anderson. There is a sample of the application you can just download it

[Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cascading-DropDownList-in-833683f9)

Here is another [blog post](http://helios.ca/2009/05/30/aspnet-mvc-cascading-dropdownlist-with-jquery/)

Hope it helps